# Setting up firebase security rules for non authenticated users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Using the product warranty registration webpage, users who purchase my product register for a warranty. The data entered by the users are written into Firestore.
However, while registering for a warranty they don't have to login or authenticate.
Is there any way to enforce security rules such a way that users entering data only on my webpage are allowed? (CORS header based etc)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Rules do not really care about CORS or any headers in your request. The ideal here would be to enforce authentication to make your data secure, in fact if you check [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#open_access), open access is considered as a not insecure Firebase Rule.

If this is not an option for you, you can try setting up a middle man that handle this specific request to Firestore that can handle CORS and request headers with some logic and that makes the actual transaction with the Firestore, for this purpose I would recommend creating a HTTP Cloud Function.

That way you can add some logic behind your request handling and actually close the access to Firestore for external users with a retrict Firebase Rule, since Cloud Functions won't be subject to those. This will however create some extra costs to your project because of the use of a Cloud Function.